# Debugging why specific font is not working in React Native

Tags: ios, fonts, react-native

I am currently using many different fonts. All of them are working except for one particular.

I added it in the same way as I added others which are working:

1. Import the font into project
2. Modify info.plist
3. Find proper font family name (I did this by plugging NSLog inside RCTConvert)
4. Use the font in react-native through CSS with fontFamily

Unfortunately I cannot share the font publicly, so I have to ask how would one debug this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible culprit is the font weight. I was trying to use a font with a weight of 325 at one point, but React Native seems to not allow the usage of a font unless the weight falls within their enum values (normal, bold, all hundreds within the range 100-900).

I used this app to modify the font weight of the file I was trying to use and set it to a standard 400: https://glyphsapp.com

Comment: Thank you John, I will give you bounty once I can.

Answer (score 2):

In AppDelegate.m, under NSURL *jsCodeLocation, paste the following code. This will log out all available fonts, including the new font(s) that you have added:

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
  NSLog(@”%@”, family);
  for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
  {
    NSLog(@” %@”, name);
  }
}
```

That way, you can get the exact font name to use in your app. The log output should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that. I see `family` but `name` is missing. If we take Savoye LET` from your example - there is no `SavoyLetPlain`

Comment: I did it again, it is actually not empty and it shows up. It is not working - it's rendering a different font: http://i.imgur.com/532gu7q.png

Comment: Can you provide an image of what your XCode project is logging out? Thanks.

Comment: Check this link: http://i.imgur.com/iF94lC9.png Impact is the font that is not working.

Comment: Ok cool, yeah you can use any of those fonts, such as 
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'Thornburi'}}> HELLO! </Text> ;

What do you mean by 'it's rendering a different font'?

Comment: I know I can use them like that and I do. But this one (Impact) in particular is not working. Check my second comment and compare it to http://www.identifont.com/samples/adobe/Impact.gif

Comment: Have you checked that your fonts are included as Resources in your bundle? Under Build Phases -> copy bundle resources?

Comment: The font is included as Resources in my bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same solution, using Swift. Here is the script to print out the Font Familes, and Faces, in Swift (works in appDelegate)

```
let fontFamilies =  UIFont.familyNames()
    for  fontNames in fontFamilies{
      print(fontNames)
        let fontFace = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(fontNames)
        for aName in fontFace{
            print("   \(aName)")
        }
    }[output of script][1]
```

link to part of log...http://www.zonesight.com/stackImages/font.png